# CSS only loads on mouse hover, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

When this page first loads there is NO CSS formatting at all until the user hovers their mouse pointer over the div elements.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>Button Magic</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            div {
                margin-left: 100px;
                height: 30px;
                width: 100px;
                border-radius: 5px;
                background-color: #69D2E7;
                text-align: center;
                color: #FFFFFF;
                font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
                font-size: 10px;
                overflow:hidden; 
                word-wrap:break-word;
                display: inline;

            }

        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('div').mouseenter(function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        height: '+=68px'
                    }, "fast");
                });

                $('div').mouseleave(function() {
                    $(this).animate({
                        height: '-=68px'
                    }); 
                });
            });
        </script>

    </head>
<body>
     <div><br/>Click Me! <br><br><img src="https://i.imgur.com/WUFGJqR.gif?1" width="75" height="47" border="0" usemap="#map"></div>
     <div><br/>Click Me! <br><br><img src="https://i.imgur.com/OxHKeTw.gif" width="75" height="47" border="0" usemap="#map" /></div>
     <div><br/>Click Me! <br><br><img src="https://i.imgur.com/ugukhx5.gif" width="75" height="47" border="0" usemap="#map" /></div>
     <div><br/>Click Me! <br><br><img src="https://i.imgur.com/01xzeLK.gif" width="75" height="47" border="0" usemap="#map" /></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your divs has `display:inline` property. .Replace it with `display:inline-block`. It should fix your problem.

Comment: Just to add to that, the reason it only works on hover is because the browser identifies that it should be `inline-block` rather than `inline` once you hover and assigns this style to the element.

Comment: GMambaG explained it above.

Comment: You also included jQuery twice.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for : http://jsfiddle.net/w9sbj0ae/

```
 div {
     margin-left: 100px;
     height: 30px;
     width: 100px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     background: #69D2E7;
     text-align: center;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     font-family: Verdana, Arial, Sans-Serif;
     font-size: 10px;
     overflow:hidden;
     word-wrap:break-word;
     display: inline-block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your position and padding rules are invalid. This might cause problems in some browsers. Either remove or comment out using `/* [some code] */`.

Does this solve the problem?